# How to customize an Observer to a action of the Controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action, observers

my question is: I need to access one action after another Controller action is accessed, completed and rendered and the second reason action will have another rendering. Observers thought to use, but from what I read they deal only with Models.

> def action_1
>
> ```
>  render :xml => {:success => "Msg success."}
> ```
>
> end
>
> def action_2
>
> ```
>  render :nothing => "", :locals => {:scheduling_id => scheduling_id}
> ```
>
> end

Comment: A controller action can only be rendered once, otherwise you'll meet double rendering error. Show the real problem need to solve, not the concept.

Comment: I know Billy, but is a different situation

Answer (score 0):

"Actions" are just method calls.  `action_1` can call `action_2`, [but you can't call `render` more than once](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors), so you have a structure problem you'll need to deal with.

Perhaps something like this is what you're going for?

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def my_action
    # ...
    my_shared_stuff
    render ...
  end

  private

  def my_shared_stuff
    # ... shared things
  end

end
```

Comment: So I wanted an Observer for when you finish render action_1 know that the Observer should now call action_2. My situation is that I need to render an xml action_1 to return from a webservice and the second access method js inside action_2.html.erb.

Comment: @RachidCalazans, a request can only ask one type, html, js, json, xml or others. How can you deliver even if you could render?

Comment: @BillyChan, I know it can only one type. So I wanted to use an Observer / Listiner in a controller. Is it possible? Or just for Models?

Comment: @RachidCalazans, you may check "Cells" gem to see if that could meet you need.